# Issue Importing Component from Personal NPM Package

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am creating a demo component library to test build systems for these kinds of libraries. I have created my component as such:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const SCButton = styled.button`
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #288a0f;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
`;

export interface Props extends ComponentProps {
    text: string;
}

interface ComponentProps {
    id?: string;
}

const Button = ({ text = 'Button Text', id }: Props) => {
    const componentProps: ComponentProps = {};
    if (id) {
        componentProps.id = id;
    }
    return <SCButton {...componentProps}>{text}</SCButton>;
};

export default Button;
```

Now I use webpack to bundle this into a dist folder. When I install the package from npm and import the component I get the following error when using it:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I have imported it like the following:

```
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'

import Button from 'design-system/dist/Button/Button'

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <Button text="hi" />
                <p>
                    Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Learn React
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I don't know what the issue is since the import and export are both default and usually this error pops up when those are out of sync.

Here is the example: https://github.com/JoshBowdenConcepts/aero-design-system

Comment: Please create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it (can be codesandbox or a github repo). It seems like your `design-system` isn't packaging the `Button` properly. For example, the code above [works locally](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-button-wumkz).

Comment: https://github.com/JoshBowdenConcepts/aero-design-system

Comment: `export { Button as default }` if you want to export a named var as default.

Comment: That is not really the goal but that is good to know. I just want to be able to import this button into another project.

Comment: Your repo appears to be private, please make it public.

Comment: @JoshBowden if you want to be able to use it in any project your import and export statements need to align. Right now they don't due to the reason I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I updated it locally and tested it and that is still not fixing the problem but I will make the repo public so share it.

Comment: @JoshBowden The problem is that you're shipping JSX Typescript [.tsx](https://i.imgur.com/qOEodfJ.png) files within your `aero-design-system`, which is anti-pattern. They should be compiled to `.js` files (either [es5](https://i.imgur.com/QMfpi8p.png) or [es6](https://i.imgur.com/lXutcgJ.png)) with supplemental Typescript [d.ts](https://i.imgur.com/vxwoXbS.png) types. Otherwise, you need your environment (like a Webpack config) to transpile Typescript within `node_modules`.

Comment: @MattCarlotta isn't babel taking care of that? I would like to add the declaration files for support but I was under the impression the babel typescript plugin handled the conversion. Is there a plugin I should add or some structure I should change?

Comment: Babel handles transpiling files within `src`, not within `node_modules`. Also, it appears that you're not packaging the `dist` folder (see *tsx* screenshot above -- its missing). Also, it appears that you're compiling React within the `dist/Button.js` file. That needs to be externalized/excluded from compilation -- otherwise, every component will contain the entire React library. On that note, Webpack isn't the best option for creating UI libraries. I'd suggest [rollupJS](https://www.rollupjs.org/guide/en/)